# Does something like a default license exists?

Tags: licensing

Imagine I found some piece of code, no information about its license. I can't find any contact information, or the contact doesn't respond.

So my question is: Is it licensed by a default license? Am I allowed to modify the code, redistribute it, sell it or what ever? Or do I have to treat this software as completely restricted stuff?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is not legal advice**

If there is any doubt in your mind of where it came from you should not use it. Just because the license isn't there doesn't mean there isn't one. Someone else could have stripped the license from the code and reposted it. That wouldn't give you carte-blanche to use it.

It is very possible that at a later date the original author who did Copyright (which he gets the copyright by default) could come after you.

In all reality it would all depend on his ability to enforce his copyright. This is what is happening will all these tech companies claiming their IP has been infringed on. The Linux, Google, Microsoft, Oracle debacles are all because of some similar problem to this.

If it isn't that complicated, just rewrite the code.

Comment: even re-writing can be problematic if you've already seen the internals of an implementation by someone else

Comment: @awoodland Agreed. You are right. At that point you have to be careful and potentially find another solution.

Comment: Not rewrite but to write new with the background what you've learned from that code. Not copy it, just write new code. Learning is allowed by the default license normally.

Answer (score 2):

The default license is - if obtained the code eligible - that you are allowed to read the code. And that's it. IANAL.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find it? A web-site (contact webmaster), a post (contact the author, or leave  amessage in the forum)? Legacy code in your company?

You should try to follow the breadcrumbs and try to get to the author to clarify it. Document what you do to contact him, so at least you can prove you have not acted in bad faith in case someone complains.

If you have done that and nothing comes out, I would use it in my code without much of a hassle. If the author wanted it copyrighted, he should have attached a copyright notice to it.

Comment: *If the author wanted it copyrighted, he should have attached a copyright notice to it* - I don't think that statement carries any legal weight at all, although it varies from country to country.

Comment: Well, one important disclaimer I forgot to add: I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice. If the code is important enough to be critical to your project, ask a lawyer about it.